# i didn't understand why " if(number%i ==0) " ->(condition is always true) ... which means this method will always return false

Tags: java, if-statement

[condition is always true , which means that the method will always return false ][1]

````
  public class Primenumber {
    public int number ;
    public void saisie(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("donnez un un entier : ");
        number = sc.nextInt();
    }
    public boolean isprime(){
        for(int i=1 ; i <= number-1 ; i++ )
            if(number%i ==0)
                return false;
        return true ;
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Typo. `int i=1` should be `int i=2` since `anything%1` == `0`.

Comment: yes, yes, i forgot to initialise with i = 2 , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line `int i=1` you have to change the value of `i` to `2`.

Why ? At the first run, when `i = 1`, any number mod `1` => `0`, because there is no rest.

If you have any number divided by `1`, there is at no time a rest.

So the right code would be:

```
public class Primenumber {
     public int number ;
     public void saisie(){
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("donnez un un entier : ");
         number = sc.nextInt();
     }
     public boolean isprime(){
         for(int i=2 ; i <= number-1 ; i++ )
             if(number%i ==0)
                 return false;
         return true ;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop, `i` will be 1, and an integer mod 1 is always 0. You want to start from 2 in stead.

Answer (score 0):

Start loop from `2` not from `1`.

```
public boolean isprime(){
    if(number < 2)
       return false
    for(int i=2 ; i <= number-1 ; i++ )
        if(number%i ==0)
            return false;
    return true ;
}
```